# How to connect my local project to an existing remote Github repository?

Tags: git

Everywhere I look, all I see is the standard:

```
git add remote origin <url>
```

followed by: `add/commit/push`

I do not want to add, commit and push anything. I just want to link my remote repository, and then be able to change branches, so I can create a new branch inside my repository, and then push stuff in it. Currently, when I do the `git add remote origin <url>`, and then do `git branch`, I see nothing. `git branch -r` also does not nothing. Why? Where are all my branches? If I do `git checkout master`, it doesn't work.

What I want is to do the same thing as cloning a repo, but instead of cloning it, I want to link it to my project. I do not want to commit or push anything into my master branch.

How do I connect it?

Comment: I'm not an expert but from experimenting, I think you need to `git fetch` in order to see remote branches with `git branch -r`, and to make a local commit before you see a local branch in `git branch`. And the reason `git checkout master` doesn't work (you don't explain what you mean by this) is that you don't have any local commits in your local repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you do not see the branches of your remote repository in you local repository is that you missed the call to `git fetch`.

Do a

```
git add remote origin <url>
git fetch origin
git branch -r
```

and you will see the remote branches in you local repository. You can then checkout to one of them by running

```
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

After that it is the usual `add/commit/push` workflow again.